# Confusion about the proof of the Metatheorem on Constants in predicate logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In *Lectures in Logic and Set Theory*(Vol.2) by George Tourlakis, there is a metatheorem and its proof (fraction) as follows:

metatheorem:[image]

proof (fraction):[image]

What confuses me is why the proof consider the cases that A[e1, . . . , en] is a nonlogical axiom, since "we did not add any new nonlogical axioms" and nonlogical axioms in the original language cannot contain constant symbols.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA A theory is axioms(logical and nonlogical) plus well-formed formulas deducible from the axioms. The point is A[e1, . . . , en] cannot be included in nonlogical axioms, since we did not add any new nonlogical axioms while extending the language.

Comment: In my edition I have "Note that $A[e_1, \ldots, e_n]$ cannot be nonlogical under our assumptions"

Comment: Ok; my ref is to Vol.1 page 47. It seems to me that your ref is to Vol.2 page 48

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA So, how about the question?

Comment: You are right; the Vol.2 version is incorrect.